# Insert of the same value into multiple lines

Tags: sql-server, database, insert, sql-insert

I have the tables flat and `plan_stat`.
Each `plan` must be present in all states, individually, so I always have an entry of plans in each row of states.
I need to enter a plan in all states at a time and I would not like to do line by line as below:

```
Insert into plano_estado (SQ_ESTADO,SQ_PLANO) values (1,14661);
Insert into plano_estado (SQ_ESTADO,SQ_PLANO) values (2,14661);
Insert into plano_estado (SQ_ESTADO,SQ_PLANO) values (3,14661);
Insert into plano_estado (SQ_ESTADO,SQ_PLANO) values (4,14661);
Insert into plano_estado (SQ_ESTADO,SQ_PLANO) values (5,14661);
Insert into plano_estado (SQ_ESTADO,SQ_PLANO) values (6,14661);
Insert into plano_estado (SQ_ESTADO,SQ_PLANO) values (7,14661);
Insert into plano_estado (SQ_ESTADO,SQ_PLANO) values (8,14661);
Insert into plano_estado (SQ_ESTADO,SQ_PLANO) values (9,14661);
Insert into plano_estado (SQ_ESTADO,SQ_PLANO) values (10,14661);
Insert into plano_estado (SQ_ESTADO,SQ_PLANO) values (11,14661);
Insert into plano_estado (SQ_ESTADO,SQ_PLANO) values (12,14661);
```

**How to do this in a more agile way? Well, I'll have to make this insert for N planes.**

table plan_stat:

[image: plan_stat]

Comment: Removed the incompatible `Oracle` tag

Comment: Are the values for SQ_ESTADO always sequential with no gaps? If so, you can use a numbers or tally table for this. If not you could use a cross join to your states table.

Comment: @SeanLange 
They are always sequences, without failure.

Comment: What table or source SQ_ESTADO is coming from?

Comment: @AndrewPaes table 'plan'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert from a select since you respect the columns order and the value type. Also you could read for basics here. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

This is going to insert for each distinct SQ_ESTADO coming from "plan" table.

```
insert into plano_estado (
    SQ_ESTADO
    ,SQ_PLANO
    )
select distinct SQ_ESTADO
    ,14661 as SQ_PLANO
from plan
```